# Read child node from one branch only

Tags: c#, combobox, xmldocument, xmlnode, child-nodes

I looked at several examples within here and it looks like I'm following the right procedure yet it still not working so I am obviously doing something wrong. 
I have two comboBox which I am trying to populate from an XML file
The idea is that once the first selection has been made the set of choices for the secondary comboBox will be generated and if i switch the first selection then the secondary comboBox should refresh as well

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ComboBox>
    <Customer name="John"/>
        <Data>
            <System>Linux</System>
        </Data>
    <Customer name="Fernando"/>
        <Data>
            <System>Microsoft</System>
            <System>Mac</System>
        </Data>
</ComboBox>
```

This is my C# code

```
//This part works the customer_comboBox is generated correctly with John and Fernando

 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +@"\comboBox.xml");
 XmlNodeList customerList = doc.SelectNodes("ComboBox/Customer");

 foreach (XmlNode node in customerList)
 {
     customer_comboBox.Items.Add(node.Attributes["name"].InnerText);
 }

//putting the selected item from the first comboBox in a string
string selected_customer = customer_comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

//This is the part that does not work
//I want to read XML node that matches selected_customer and populate systems available

foreach (XmlNode node in customerList)
{
      if (node.Attributes["name"].InnerText == selected_customer) 
      {
          foreach (XmlNode child in node.SelectNodes("ComboBox/Customer/Data"))
          {
             system_comboBox.Items.Clear();
             system_comboBox.Items.Add(node["System"].InnerText); 
          }
      } 
}
```

I gone two days straight trying to figure this out. Not sure if my XML is wrong or the way im calling the child node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code and I've the following changes.

#### 1. The XML-file

The Customer node was closed and isn't nesting the Data/System nodes. This results in the following two xpaths:

1. ComboBox/Customer;
2. ComboBox/Data/System;

By nesting the Data/System nodes inside the Customer nodes is the first part of the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ComboBox>
  <Customer name="John">
    <Data>
      <System>Linux</System>
    </Data>
  </Customer>
  <Customer name="Fernando">
    <Data>
      <System>Microsoft</System>
      <System>Mac</System>
    </Data>
  </Customer>
</ComboBox>
```

#### 2. The change in code

The change in the XML structure simplifies the xpath usage in the "node.SelectNodes()" statement to just include "Data/System". I also simplified "node["System"].InnerText" to "child.InnerText":

```
foreach (XmlNode node in customerList)
{
    if (node.Attributes["name"].InnerText == selected_customer)
    {
        system_comboBox.Items.Clear();

        foreach (XmlNode child in node.SelectNodes("Data/System"))
        {
            system_comboBox.Items.Add(child.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. Remove this block

Because the Customer list needs it's items to already exist at runtime. Add the items manually to the combobox and remove this block:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in customerList)
{
    customer_comboBox.Items.Add(node.Attributes["name"].InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! so my XML was not in the right format. It works now, only thing is that when I select "Fernando" it only outputs "Mac" it skips "Microsoft"

Comment: @Fernando I've also fixed that problem for ya. Check out the updated answer. You'll have to move the Clear() outside of the foreach, because after adding a new item to the system_combobox the previous item gets cleared.

Comment: No problem @Fernando. Glad to be of any help

Comment: @Fernando, don't forget to mark my answer as the answer to your question.